# why CanvasRenderingContext2D is not defined in my IE9?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript HTML5 application based on prototype model, I extend CanvasRenderingContext2D of Canvas to support drawing ellipse and so on.

Sudenly an error shows CanvasRenderingContext2D is undefined, and getContext is undefined either.

What caused this problem?

Comment: Missing/misplaced doc type declaration?

Comment: my declaration is <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: suddenly ?? check u have changed IE9 to IE8 in webdeveloper

Comment: Placed at the first line in the file without any preceeding characters? Compatible mode or other browser/document mode than IE9? Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: I tried with opening a website which has HTML5 Canvas, it seems working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, somehow my IE9's **Compatibility View** is turned on. This means if you  turn IE9's compatibility View on it doesn't support HTML5 anymore.

Comment: For what it is worth, that is because IE9's compatibility mode puts the browser back into an IE7 engine basically. IE7 definitely doesn't support HTML5 ;-)